# htaccess not rules with index and another page with param

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a problem to configure a simple htaccess with two pages to rewrite: the index and the page.php?param=valueparam

The problem is that one of these rules its correct the another don't work.

These is that I need:

- index.php ->  mydomain.com/
- page.php?param=valueparam  ->  mydomain.com/valueparam

I tried several options but anything rules that I want:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options -Indexes

php_value default_charset None
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]*)$ page.php?param=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for posting your efforts in your question. Could you please do let us know if `mydomain.com/valueparam` is the link you are hitting in browser? Which you want to serve with `page.php?param=valueparam` in backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your shown samples only, could you please try following htaccess rules file, please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##For index.php -> mydomain.com as per OP's first condition.
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(valueparam)/?$ page.php?param=$1 [NC,L]
```